# USEMAP and ONCLICK both used on IMG Tag not working in Firefox

Tags: javascript, firefox, onclick

I have an IMG tag with USEMAP and ONCLICK, when a user clicks the map I need to set a javascript variable that is then used in the map that calls a function.  If I comment out ONCLICK in the IMG the Map calls the function without issue.  IF I comment out the USEMAP the ONCLICK fires it sets the value, they just wont play nice together.  IS there anyway I can use the ONCLICK to set the variable and USEMAP together in firefox, this works fine in IE. (sample code is below)

```
    <map NAME="map3" > 
       <area HREF="javascript:alert('Need to call a function here and pass value for myfield.  value of myfield = ' + myfield)"  COORDS="0,0,10,12"> 
      <area  HREF="javascript:readAnnotation('brsfld', myfield)" COORDS="11,0,20,12">   
     </map> 

    <body>


     <CFSET fld = "CBT001"> 
<IMG SRC="ComQ4.gif" height="12" width="30" BORDER="0"  TABINDEX="-1" ALT=""  USEMAP="#map3"  onclick="alert('here we are');myfield='#fld#';">

     This is my test.

     </body> </html>
```

Comment: `<map>` is out of the `<body>`? Is this right?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your map name appears in both the MAP and IMG tag like the following:

```
<map name="map3">...

<img src="yoururlhere" usemap="#map3"> // not #Map3
```

**Update:**

Try by adding an event handler

Adding an event handler is pretty straight forward as you might expect. I'll be using jQuery for the demonstration.

```
$(function() {
    $('map[name=my-map] #fave-area').click(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        alert('Clicked!');
    });
});
```

Image map:

```
<map name="my-map">
    <area id="fav-area" shape=poly, coords="0,0, 46,0, 46,46" href="#fav"> 
</map>
```

Useful link..http://www.damiangalarza.com/posts/javascript/bringing-back-the-image-map/

Comment: unfortunaly that still isn't my problem, i fixed that in my sample code and the alert in the map will come up but the alert will not display from my onclick event.  I need onClick to fire first then the usemap any suggestions. thanks.

Comment: @user3241545 can you try by adding an event handler.. See updated answer..and let me know.